# How to speed up fetching of data from server using JSON?

Tags: android, json

I am building an app that is fetching data from sever using JSON in android. There are like 3000 records that are fetched and the loading seems rather slow. The code to fetch data is as follows -

```
public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(url));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
//          in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
//                  .getContent()));
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                    .getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }

            in.close();

            String result = sb.toString();

            return result;
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there anything that can be done to speed up the fetching? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below image :-

[image]

For quick response you have to use retrofit.

http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/

Comment: Can you help me get started with retrofit because the content on the net is confusing me. Suppose I have a PHP script at www.kurdshopping.net/apj/subcat.php which has to be called with get method using parameter id=15 say. How do I call the script using retrofit?

Comment: @Pankaj visit these sites  https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit   and this one  https://medium.com/mindorks/android-series-using-retrofit-to-consume-apis-67e047e375d